# Magento 2 : Readiness check error during installation

Tags: magento2, php, admin, cron

I am getting readiness check error during magento installation.Can any help to fix this issue? Where can I find another php.ini file for command line in xampp? I've read also that this could be something with cron, but it shows that I configured it well.[image]

Comment: Which OS  are you using ?

Comment: Windows 10, php 7.0.26

Comment: it should be under C:\xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: I know that, of course, I changed it, as you can see it's even bigger than needed. I've also tried just "756M", but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you restart the apache ?

Comment: Yes, i've restarted the server

Answer (score 0):

Its clearly mentioned in `PHP Settings Check`  that you need to change values in `php.ini` file.

Where can I find another php.in ?

One of the way is to hit below function from a file.

// Save it in a file where you put others projects.

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

In browser search  `ctrl + f`  for php.ini it against it file path is mentioned.

if your using xampp UI then in xampp config button is present click on that a dropdown will surely come select php.ini and cnage the value as per your need.

As in this case just set correct memory limit to `756M`

Where can I find another php.ini file for command line ?

> php -i

Once changed the value kindly restart your xampp.

If even after changing vlues in php.ini it still shows the wrong value kindy have a look to below link.

https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/PHP-Settings-Check-fail-displaying-wrong-memory-limit/td-p/42872/page/2

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I've done wrong with command-lines, cron was working, but not as it should, so i've deleted generated files like .setup-cronjob-status and changed those lines from devdocs to look like this one:

```
php -c c:\xampp\php\php.ini c:\xampp\htdocs\magento\bin\magento cron:run
```

and now all works.